# Facebook C# authentication example

Tags: authentication, facebook-c#-sdk

Authentication [examples are missing](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Authentication%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation) from the documentation.

Would it be possible to have an authentication example for a desktop application, not a [web one?](http://multitiered.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/getting-started-with-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/)

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you are looking for?  The SDK comes with win forms and silverlight examples, both of which are desktop applications.

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing a desktop application, consider using [Facebook PowerShell Module](http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com). I would be interested to know more about your scenario! Jon

Comment: Do you mean that Facebook C# SDK is intended for web applications rather than desktop applications? I just want to access some information from a Console application.

Comment: I don't mean to suggest that Facebook C# SDK is inappropriate for desktop applications. However, PowerShell is an established technology for IT automation, including but not limited to scripting. Depending on your background, you may find it easier and faster to implement your scenario over PowerShell rather than a full-bore .NET application.